Is zero-phase component analysis (ZCA) equivalent to substituting singular values with $\sqrt{n}$?
Consider the (centered) dataset $X \in R^{n \times p}$, with $n$ samples and $p$ features. According to this solution, the zero-phase component analysis (ZCA) is simply a re-rotation of PCA:
$$W_{ZCA} = E W_{PCA} = E D^{-1/2} E^T$$
where $E$ and $D$ are matrices involved in the eigendecomposition of the correlation matrix:
$$C = \frac{1}{n}X^T X = E D E^T \in R ^{p \times p}$$
The spherized representation of $X$ can then be cast as $\bar X = X W_{ZCA}$.
Now, if we use SVD of the data $X = U\Sigma V^T$ and substitute it in the correlation matrix C, we find $V = E$ and $D = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma^2$. Then, the spherized representation can be written simply as:
$$\bar X = X ED^{-1/2}E^T = U \Sigma (V^T E) D^{-1/2}E^T = U (\Sigma D^{-1/2}) E^T = \sqrt{n} U I E^T =U (\sqrt{n} I) V^T$$
So, this suggests that ZCA is effectively equivalent to substituting the singular values with the $\sqrt{n}$. I never saw this explanation anywhere, which makes me think that it might be incorrect.
Is my calculation right? Can we treat ZCA as equalizing the singular values?

Can you please edit your post to exxplain what is ZCA?

@kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks for noting that my question is not as clear enough.I updated it.

I also find this quite helpful: https://jermwatt.github.io/control-notes/posts/zca_sphereing/ZCA_Sphereing.html
